# angular: resolving circular dependency in services

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm struggling with this error on my angular app. I have a service (Service A) that depends on another service (service B). Now Service B needs to call Service A, and this is causing circular dependency and I'm getting 'Can't resolve all parameters for Service A'.

I tried creating service C that calls Service A and injecting that into Service B, but the error is still there. I can think of two ways

1) Combining service A and B - this would make the service super long, and the class would have so many dependencies. But it solves the circular dependency issue nicely.

2) extract the shared dependency to additional service - The thing is that shared dependency is function - the business logic from service B needs to be used in service A.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to resolve this.

Comment: I'm wondering where the third option is. Can you also show us stripped down code and the exactly error message you're getting?

Comment: Without any more information, I would vote for option 2. Seems that it would have the cleanest separation of concerns. But as @yurzui says, showing some code would help us better help you.

Comment: A third way would be use angular's injector in service B: `constructor( private injector: Injector)` and then get a reference to service A like that `this.injector.get(ServiceA)`